# Eigen: how to remove an initialised coefficient from a sparse Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I am writing a backward elimination algorithm. At each iteration I need to eliminate some coefficients from a column of a SparseMatrix and update the other non zero ones.

However, changing a reference to a coefficient to zero does not deallocate it, so the number of non zero coefficients is the same. How do I delete the reference? I tried with makeCompressed() to no avail and pruned is not known by the compiler.

Basic code below.

How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
void nukeit(){
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(4, 3);
  cout << "non zeros of empty: " << A.nonZeros() << "\n" << endl;

  A.insert(0, 0) = 1;
  A.insert(2, 1) = 5;
  cout <<  "non zeros are two: " << A.nonZeros() << "\n" << endl;

  A.coeffRef(0, 0) = 0;
  cout <<  "non zeros should be one but it's 2: " << A.nonZeros() << "\n" << endl;

  cout <<  "However the matrix has only one non zero element\n" << A << endl;
}
```

Output

```
non zeros of empty: 0

non zeros are two: 2

non zeros should be one but it's 2: 2

However the matrix has only one non zero element
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 5 0 
0 0 0
```

Comment: I noticed that there are several posts tagged "eigen" on the Computational Science forum: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=eigen maybe you could also post there?

Comment: @ Baruchel Not much of an answer but a great tip :-) thanks! I found a link there to a post on stackoverflow. The solution is very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting some of the coefficients of the current column to zero, you can explicitly remove them by calling `A.prune(0.0)`. See the respective [doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#aa4592d803de19800d8fb3cb07a5036b6).

However, be aware that this will trigger a costly memory copy of the remaining column entries. With sparse matrices, we usually never work in-place.

Comment: If `A.prune(0)` doesn't compile, try `A.prune(0.0)`.

Comment: Yes, I found it while you responded. many thanks. And indeed `A.prune(0)` gives a weird compiler error. prune(0.0) works.

Comment: @ggael Hi, I was so happy to have found a solution that I overlooked the second part of your answer. I don't understand what you mean by "not working in-place". Can you suggest a better approach?